"File Can't Be Opened" No package contents at the DMG file. How can I install anything?
The application that I'm trying to install has no package contents there's only a DMG file.
How can I proceed through the terminal without having to run through the package contents of the application?

a DMG file in this context is a disk image, so you must mount it first using whatever mechanism macs use for virtualdisks.

Most Mac apps install by double-clicking the dmg to mount it, then copying the app to Applications. There's often even a link to Applications in the dmg itself. You then eject the dmg - select & Cmd/E. You can then throw it away unless you like to archive your installers.
